# Debugging $Scope Updates using Angular.js 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a UI/JS Newbie trying to learn Angular.js through a SPA project.

However, I just see my `<Variable Name>` when I use `{{Variable Name}};` whereas instead I would have expected to see my `<Variable Value>` instead.

- I've verified that Angular is getting loaded for my SPA.
- I've verified there are no error message logs in my Http Server console.
- I then tried to print to my browser console the `$scope.myVar` from within the Controller function after setting it; and also from my index.html after loading my controller.js.
- I also installed the ng-inspector extension for my Chrome browser.

However, nothing is getting displayed in either case!

- Here's my controllers.js:

"

```
angular.module('todoApp.controller', [])

.controller('todoController', ["$scope", function($scope){

/* CHECK controller function entered */
document.write("* INSPECTING SCOPE WITHIN CONTROLLER *");
console.log("* INSPECTING SCOPE WITHIN CONTROLLER *");

$scope.oneWayOutput = "WHOOHOO! Howdy World!";
$scope.twoWayInput = "UPDATE ME and SEE ME CHANGE!";

/* CHECK variables set */
console.log($scope.oneWayOutput);
console.log($scope.twoWayInput);

}]);
```

"

- Here's my index.html:

"

```
<body ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="todoController">

<script type="text/javascript"  src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    <!-- CHECK Angular got loaded OK -->
    if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        document.write("FACE-PLANT loading Angular!");
    }
    else {
        document.write("SUCCESS loading Angular!")
    }

    <!-- CHECK scope variable contents at this point -->
    var controllerElement = document.querySelector('body');
    var controllerScope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
    console.log(controllerScope.oneWayOutput);

</script>


<!-- TEST OUTPUT JS scope data variable output here, as accessed from        single controller bound to app module here! -->
</br></br>{{oneWayOutput}}</br></br>

<!-- TEST INPUT data -->
<input type="text" ng-model="twoWayInput"/></br>
<!-- TEST IMMEDIATE changed output upon editting input -->
{{twoWayInput}}</br>
```

"

- Here's my app.js:

"

```
angular.module('todoApp',[
    'todoApp.controller'
    ]);
```

"

Comment: any errors thrown in dev tools console? Are the console logs in controller showing up? Show us the basic relevant view html also

Comment: if you could setup a plunker or something i'll check it, and for now check whether you set up ng-app="todoApp" on any tag (eg <body ng-app="todoApp">) and check if you forgot to declare tag with ng-controller="todoController" inside ng-app tag and then add your {{oneWayOutput}} inside tag with ng-controller

Comment: I recently discovered Chrome Developer Tools!  It showed an error in the Console that controllers.js wasn't found -- and I fixed my problem there; it works now!!

Answer (score 0):

try to update your markup like this

```
<div ng-app="todoApp">
  <div ng-controller="todoController">
    {{oneWayOutput}}
    <hr />
    <input ng-model="twoWayInput" />
    {{twoWayInput}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already had both ng-app and ng-controller directives in the body tag. Had to add a blank line in comment for StackOverflow to display my index.html code completely for this.   Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem with proper display of values for either the 'oneWayOutput', or the 'twoWayInput' variables.

Comment: I've looked elsewhere for examples of a "HelloWorld" app; and it seems like those examples don't separate out the app.js from the controllers.js.  Instead, they have the controller code in the same file as the app.js; which isn't as clean structurally.  I will try that to get something basic to work; but I really want to understand exactly how to get a function within a separate controllers.js file to execute! i.e. How exactly to reference its contents from the main app.js?  This latter approach would be a more extensible code structure, and I want to understand how to do that!

Comment: OK; after some more experimenting; I've got this working with the expected output to the Browser!  YAY!

Comment: usually examples declare app and controllers and directives in one place in js file just to reduce confusion, you definitely should declare each directive, controller and other stuff in their own js files

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the html. There is an extra quote which is throwing out the bindings.

Try removing the duplicate quote from this part: input type=""text" (the second last line just above the twowayinput binding).

Comment: I fixed that after noticing it on my IntelliJ syntax highlighting.  Thanks, but this doesn't fix the problem with proper display of values for either the 'oneWayOutput', or the 'twoWayInput' variables.

Answer (score 0):

OK; after some more experimenting and discovering how to use Chrome Dev Tools Console; I've got this working now!  Root problems had to do with how I was specifying how to load controller code from a separate file.  YAY! Posting the details of my solution to help other newbies like myself!!

0) Inspecting JS on Chrome browser:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/?hl=en

1) src/app.js looks like:

```
angular.module('todoApp', []);
```

2) src/controllers.js looks like:

```
angular.module('todoApp')
   .controller('controller1', ["$scope", function($scope){
       console.log("* INSPECTING SCOPE WITHIN CONTROLLER *");
       $scope.oneWayOutput = 'WHOOHOO! Howdy World!';
       $scope.twoWayInput = "UPDATE ME and SEE ME CHANGE!";
       console.log($scope.oneWayOutput);
       console.log($scope.twoWayInput);   }]);
```

3) src/index.html looks like:

```
<body ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="controller1">

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

    if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
      document.write("FACE-PLANT loading Angular!");
    }
    else {
      document.write("SUCCESS loading Angular!")
    }

    <!-- CHECK scope variable contents at this point -->
    var controllerElement = document.querySelector('body');
    var controllerScope = angular.element(controllerElement).scope();
    console.log(controllerScope.oneWayOutput);

</script>

</br></br>{{oneWayOutput}}</br></br>

<input type="text" ng-model="twoWayInput"/></br>
<!-- TEST IMMEDIATE changed output upon editting input -->
{{twoWayInput}}</br>
```